# No ParameterResolver registered for parameter

Tags: junit, automated-tests, parametrized-testing

I have this error on a parametrized test:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [java.lang.String arg1] in method [public void myTest(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)].
```

Can't find the problem, everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `@CsvFileSource(files = "myFile.csv", delimiter = ',')`

But the actual delimiter was ';'.